# Two distinct graph objects for same URL?

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

When I lint a URL through Facebook's Linter / Debugger, it generates a Graph Object structured like [Obj#1] https://graph.facebook.com/380728101301 (I'm using Facebook's IMDB example so it's clear it's not just me). While this object has an id associated with it, this id does not work as a pageId in Graph API functions (pages.isFan for example).

Previously, it was the case that I could access the same Graph Object I had linted by using that object's URL as the id in the Graph. For the IMDB example, that's https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/ (this also maps to [Obj#2] graph.facebook.com/114324145263104 if you just swap the id from the result back into the URL).

However, even though it seems like that should be the same graph object as what was linted, it is a different object with a different id. This object's id **can be used** with the open graph api functions, but the object itself is not actually generated until someone has explicitly liked the URL, which is not particularly convenient.

So not only does the linter no longer seem to generate usable objects on its own, but it also appears that two different objects are being generated by Facebook from **the same metadata at the same url**. Confusing.

My questions are:

1) What is the difference between these two Graph Objects?

- Obj#1 -- graph.facebook.com/380728101301
- Obj#2 -- graph.facebook.com/114324145263104

2) Is there still a way to generate an Graph Object with a valid pageId (like Obj#2) before someone has explicitly liked the page the og metadata is on?

Comment: I just posted a similar question here?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746767/object-debugger-and-graph-api-return-different-objects-for-same-url-likes

Answer (score 0):

> https://graph.facebook.com/380728101301 (I'm using Facebook's IMDB
>   example so it's clear it's not just me). While this object has an id
>   associated with it, this id does not work as a pageId in Graph API
>   functions (pages.isFan for example).

pages.isFan is not a graph API function but a legacy REST API method. from pages.isFan doc:

> Checks whether a user is a fan of a given Page. Doesn't work for
>   Application about Pages.

your first id = application about page, that's why it doesn't work.

hope this helps