# Object Debugger and Graph API return different objects for same URL?... "Likes" plugin creates separate object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-social-plugins

I used the Open Graph to define a custom object that has a plethora of meta tags.

When I use the Object Debugger / URL Linter (found here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and input my page URL that has the appropriate meta tags, Facebook scrapes my page exactly as expected, returning an object with all my meta-data as well as a unique facebook ID. This is what the Object looks like:

```
{
   "url": "http://mysite.com/8/the-dali-lama-returns",
   "type": "mysite:event",
   "title": "The Dali Lama Returns",
   "image": [
      {
         "url": "http://images.mysite.com/4f713f5e-cdd1-4b67-8f66-5ca139f24e73"
      }
   ],
   "description": "The Dali Lama will speak, and we will listen.",
   "site_name": "mysite",
   "data": {
      "when": "Thu 3:30PM, Jun 28",
      "geolocation": {
         "latitude": 34.08536,
         "longitude": -118.273994
      },
      "start": "44461-10-20T12:00:00+0000",
      "category": "literary",
      "id": 8,
      "venue": {
         "street_address": "1130 Westerly Terrace",
         "locality": "Los Angeles",
         "region": "CA",
         "postal_code": "90026"
      }
   },
   "updated_time": "2012-03-17T01:48:51+0000",
   "id": "1015073609xxxxxxx",
   "application": {
      "id": "478xxxxxxx",
      "name": "Mysite",
      "url": "https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=478xxxxxxx"
   }
}
```

**I then run into two problems:**

**1) "Likes" can't be established with my open graph object.**

When I "like" my page using the "Like" plugin that I've dropped on it, the "likes" connection isn't established with the Object shown above, but instead what appears to be a newly created object which has a limited set of meta-data.

Specifically, looking at "me/likes", the ID that is shown for the page I just liked returns the following object (using this query: graph.facebook.com/{like_id}:

```
{
   "id": "17678692xxxxxxx",
   "name": "The Dali Lama Returns",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/161984_176786925772923_6855xxxxxxx.jpg",
   "link": "http://mysite.com/8/the-dali-lama-returns",
   "likes": 1,
   "app_id": 478xxxxxxx,
   "category": "Unknown",
   "is_published": true,
   "description": "The Dali Lama will speak, and we will listen.",
   "about": "The Dali Lama will speak, and we will listen.",
   "can_post": true
}
```

So my first question: **Why is the likes connection not established with my original object shown at the top? and instead made with this new, limited object?**

**2) Object Debugger & Graph API return a different Object for the same URL**

Adding to my confusion on this, if I do the following query:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/http://mysite.com/8/the-dali-lama-returns
```

The second, limited object is returned.

And then once again, if I go to the Object Debugger and enter "http://mysite.com/8/the-dali-lama-returns" as my url (as I did initially), the first, complete object is returned.

**Why are these two queries returning different Objects?**

3) Last comment/question - news feed displays limited content...

As you would expect, when my page like appears in my news feed, it appears with only a "title", "description" and "image" versus with the complete set of information that I designed it to appear with using the Open Graph wizard. For example the When, Where information is left off.

**How can I get the news feed item I designed using the Open Graph tutorial to appear in the news feed when someone likes my page?**

Comment: what happens when you try to get the liked object directly? i.e. `https://graph.facebook.com/17678692xxxxxxx`